# Is interval call back unnecessary in multipage Dash App in Python?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am building a multi-page web application using Plotly-Dash in Python.
One of the pages has an interval callback, which reloads data from an SQL server every one hour.
It's occurred to me that maybe the interval callback is not necessary because the multi-page app calls each app when it's requested. 
Does anyone know about it?
Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the structure of your app. Is the data loaded in global scope? Saved to disk? Or queried in a callback? Some example code would make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: @emher it's queried only in the callback.

Comment: In that case, I guess your data will always by up to date (the data will be queried on each page refresh).

Comment: @emher Then I can remove the interval component! Thank you so much!